# PHP Javascript HTML5 audio in safari / IE

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5-audio

Currently using ogg, according to this I need to use MP3 for IE and Safari

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

What is the best javascript / PHP solution for playing the alert in safari and IE?

At this stage I think I need to detect browser in PHP and write the HTML mp3 file, just wondering if there is a neater solution

This is what I currently do

```
<script>

document.getElementById("alert").play();

</script>

<audio id='alert' src='/library/sounds/alert.ogg'></audio>
```

Comment: Instead of w3schools, you may want to look at [this compatible table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use wav files and mp3's. The only browser that doesn't support WAV is Internet Explorer 9+ ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats))

You can embed multiple file types like so:

```
<audio id="alert" preload="auto">
  <source src="/library/sounds/alert.wav" type="audio/wav">
  <source src="/library/sounds/alert.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

I would also recommend preloading the audio so it will play immediately when you run your `document.getElementById("alert").play();` command.